# Converting year format in a column and joining 3 other columns to the result in pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

My data is in the form below however, I managed to put it in a dataframe but now I need to convert the 77  1977 and then create one column with YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm and use it as the index.

An example of my data:

[image: an example of my data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and last if necessary [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) these columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'YY':[77,77,77],
                   'MM':[1,2,4],
                   'DD':[1,3,5],
                   'hh':[1,3,5],
                   'mm':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3]})

print (df)
   DD  F  MM  YY  hh  mm
0   1  7   1  77   1   5
1   3  4   2  77   3   3
2   5  3   4  77   5   6

df.index= pd.to_datetime(df['YY']*100000000
                         +df['MM']*1000000
                         +df['DD']*10000
                         +df['hh']*100
                         +df['mm'],format='%y%m%d%H%M')

df.drop(['YY','MM','DD','hh','mm'], axis=1, inplace=True)
print (df)
                     F
1977-01-01 01:05:00  7
1977-02-03 03:03:00  4
1977-04-05 05:06:00  3
```

Another solution with `rename` columns, but it works only in version [`0.18.1`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#assembling-datetimes):

```
df['YY'] = df.YY + 1900
df = df.rename(columns={'YY':'year','MM':'month','DD':'day','hh':'hour','mm':'minute'})

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df[['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'minute']])
print (df)

                     day  F  month  year  hour  minute
1977-01-01 01:05:00    1  7      1  1977     1       5
1977-02-03 03:03:00    3  4      2  1977     3       3
1977-04-05 05:06:00    5  3      4  1977     5       6
```

Comment: What if it was a case where we had: